# Is there any way to load csv data into a snowflake table and report if each record has been loaded successfully? (using Python)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to load data(csv file) into snowsql table using copy into command.
I also want to **display/report a message** to know if all the records are loaded successfully, if not **loaded successfully which record is unable to load**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake table function VALIDATE, might be of help:

Validates the files loaded in a past execution of the COPY INTO  command and returns all the errors encountered during the load, rather than just the first error.

Return errors for the last executed COPY command:

```
select * from table(validate(t1, job_id => '_last'));
```

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html#validate